# с++ GetModuleHandle 2

Tags: c++, winapi

С помощью функции LoadLibraryEx включил client.dll библиотеку. Мне требуется получить адрес client.dll файла с помощью функции GetModuleHandle.

```
HMODULE library = LoadLibraryEx("D://libs//client.dll",NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
```

GetModuleHandle (??);

Как мне в аргументы функции getmodulehandle включить переменную library, просто так не получится, т.к тип данных совершенно другой и выдает ошибку. Или может быть я что-то не так понял, и после LoadLibraryEx не нужно использовать getmodulehandle.

Comment: А зачем вам `GetModuleHandle`? Вам же пришёл `HMODULE` из `LoadLibraryEx`.

Comment: Кстати, а почему `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`? Для какой цели вам нужна библиотека?

Comment: Т.е. getmodulehandle и loadlibraryex идентичны ?

Comment: @VladD, библиотека нужна для того, чтобы получить её адрес, сложив с адресами определенных значений из процесса. В итоге получив статический адрес, ведь адрес значения, который мне нужен меняется.

Comment: Ну, а почему бы просто не почитать документацию на [`GetModuleHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Цитирую: GetModuleHandle function Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. The module **must have been loaded** by the calling process. Return value: If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the specified module.

Comment: Там не написано ничего, кроме описания аргументов и парочку замечаний. Моя проблема не решается с документацией.

Comment: LoadLibraryEx function **Loads** the specified module into the address space of the calling process. Return value If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the loaded module.

Comment: То есть и та, и другая возвращают хэндл на модуль. Вторая грузит его, а первая требует, чтобы он был уже загружен.

Comment: А зачем вам адрес библиотеки?

Comment: А как сложить значения ? допустим library (адрес) c переменной 
offset, которая равна 0x4b803 (опред. адрес)

Comment: Сложить что, простите? Адрес — это указатель. Я надеюсь, вы не принимаете хэндл за адрес?

Comment: Похоже что принимаю. Мне нужно получить адрес именно и в дальнейшем сложить его с указателем и получить значение.

Comment: Написал в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, для того, чтобы получить базовый адрес модуля в памяти, надо воспользоваться структурой [`MODULEINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-moduleinfo), в которой он и содержится.

Структуру `MODULEINFO` можно добыть при помощи [`GetModuleInformation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation), скормив ему хэндл на модуль (`HMODULE`). Сам хэндл можно получить либо во время загрузки модуля ([`LoadLibraryEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa)), либо если модуль уже загружен, а у вас не сохранился хэндл, через [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexa).

---

Уточнение: Обратите внимание, вам нужно будет загрузить модуль *без* флага `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`! Иначе `GetModuleInformation` [не сработает](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141120-00/?p=43573).

Comment: @Dimcheg: обновил ответ

Comment: А что тогда использовать в аргументе flasg ? NULL ?

Comment: Ещё когда я убираю этот флаг, приложение требует другие DLL библиотеки, которые видимо требует client.dll

Comment: @Dimcheg: Угу, это да. Т. к. для корректной инициализации этого самого модуля нужны, судя по всему, другие библиотеки.

Comment: @Dimcheg: Может быть, вы захотите передать `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` или там `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR`.

Comment: Какой флаг мне тогда использовать ? и да эти флаг, которые Вы написали не признает, ошибка.

Comment: @Dimcheg: Ну, не признаёт флаги наверное потому, что вы не подключили какой-нибудь header. Все флаги взяты из [официальной документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Можно в конце-концов указать просто `0`.

Comment: Так, а если я укажу NULL или 0, то у меня потребует другие DLL библиотеки, которые по всему видимому подключены в client.dll. 
И + GetModuleInformation выдает ошибку. ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _GetModuleInformation@16 в функции _main

Comment: @Dimcheg: `GetModuleInformation` требует подключения `Kernel32.lib` или `Psapi.lib`, посмотрите в документации. Зависимые библиотеки и правда нужны, но как же без этого? Для чего вам эта dll?

Comment: У меня подключен заголовок psapi.h. "Для чего вам эта dll ?" если вы про client.dll, то слушайте. В Client.dll имеется необходимое значение, адрес которого я знаю (08DF06D8). Если я просто выведу в консоль (exe) это значение с помощью функции ReadProcessMemory, то оно без сомнений выводится. Закрываем процесс, открываем заново. Запускаем нашу программу для чтения(консолька) и видим, что значения нету, т.к адрес памяти динамический. Поэтому мне и нужно получить адрес client.dll, чтобы далее я смог сложить client.dll(адрес)+1206D8(указатель)=значение. Тем самым получу статический адрес.

Comment: @Dimcheg: psapi.h — это для описания функция, а для правильной линковки, вам нужно подключить `lib` тоже. Загляните в настройки проекта.

Comment: @Dimcheg: Ничего не понял снова. У вас есть значение прямо в файле? Ну так прочитайте его из файла, делов-то! Зачем загружать dll в память?

Comment: Проблема с GetModuleInformation ушла, но вот теперь с флагами для LoadLibraryEx... Запускаю программу, требует ещё dll файлы. Этого не должно быть.

Comment: @Dimcheg; Смотрите ещё раз. Если значение статическое, модуль не должен работать, то вся эта механика не нужна, вы просто читаете значение из файла по нужному смещению. Если значение динамическое, модуль должен работать и получает значение в процессе работы, то без его зависимостей (dll-ок) не обойтись никак.

Comment: нужно использовать какой-то спец. флаг.

Comment: Есть такая же реализация всего этого, там используется только GetModuleHandle, без GetModuleInformation. Могу залить исходник на какой-либо файлообменник и Вы посмотрите как там реализовано. Правда там dll приложение, а не exe.